# Как восстановить право записи файлов на Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

При попытке установить плагин пишет "не удалось создать директорию". Как восстановить полные права на запись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через ftp или командную строку на сервере (если есть туда доступ). Папки должны иметь права 755, файлы - 644.

Вот так в Filezilla это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]